# Getting the world coordinates of multiple kinects

Tags: c#, coordinates, kinect, emgucv, markers

I have some Kinects placed in a big room.
I don't know their positions, but i placed a marker in a known positions.
I want to discover the positions of the kinects in world coordinates.

Example: Kinect1 sees marker1, and obviously can get the marker position in its own world coordinates, lets say (4, 5, 1)
Kinect2 sees marker1 at coordinates (9, 9, 8).

The marker's coordinates in the world are (3, 3, 0) where the last one is the height because the marker is on the floor.

I need to know how to get the kinects positions in the same world reference system of the marker. i've being trying this for a lot of time but i can't find a solution.

I'm using C# and EMGU wrapper for OpenCV

Comment: I think you will need more than one marker, or else you wont know the rotation of the two kinects around the marker. also, your program needs to know the position of both markers in the room, if you want the result in the coord system of the room

Comment: Also note that depth sensing is [not particularly accurate](http://mathnathan.com/2011/02/depthvsdistance/) beyond 10 feet.